# FBSDKAppInviteDialog on iOS 9 & 10 (FB SDK 4.2.0) stopped loading on 'showFromViewController'

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to perform a FBSDKAppInviteDialog request using Facebook's iOS 4.2.0 sdk but the modal share dialog page never loads.

I was able to do this just last week but now every time I call this 'showFromViewController' method, the UIWebView that opens is left blank and loading infinitely.

Has anyone experienced this? I'm encountering the issue on iOS 9 and 10.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content = [FBSDKAppInviteContent new];
content.promotionText = @"Text";
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:controller
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.
Thanks!

Comment: added more info below.. since in comments you cant really put more data like the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the deprecated UIActionSheet to open the dialog?  Try opening the dialog without it, or with the new UIAlertController.  That did the trick for me.